# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�a) VALUES

Tags: php, mysqli

hola he visto muchos videos de como subir datos a mi base de datos pero no logro hacer que funcione tengo este código en conexión

```
<?php
//establecer conexion, si funciona
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","ferremex") or die("No se pudo conectar");
?>
```

tengo este código en mi formulario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <form action ="registro.php" method ="POST">
        <input type="text" name = "name" placeholder="Nombre Completo:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="text" name = "street" placeholder="Calle:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="text" name = "house" placeholder="Numero de Casa:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="number" name = "postalNum" placeholder="Codigo Postal:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="text" name = "country" placeholder="Pais:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="text" name = "state" placeholder="Estado:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="text" name = "city" placeholder="Ciudad:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="number" name = "phoneNumer" placeholder="Telefono:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="text" name = "email" placeholder="Correo Electronico:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="text" name = "emailC" placeholder="Confirmar Correo Electronico:" value=""/><br> 
        </br>
        <input type="password" name = "password" placeholder="Contraseña:" value=""/><br></br>
        <input type="password" name = "passwordC" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña:" value=""/><br> 
         </br>          
        <p><input type = "submit" value ="aceptar"/>
    </form>
</center>
</body>
```

y este es el código para insertar los datos a la base de datos.

```
<?php
 include("conexion.php");
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $street = $_POST['street'];

 $house = $_POST['house'];
 $postal = $_POST['postalNum'];
 $country = $_POST['country'];
 $state = $_POST['state'];
 $city = $_POST['city'];
 $phone = $_POST['phoneNumer'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $re = "INSERT INTO clientes(NombreCompleto, Calle, NumCasa, CodigoPostal, Pais, Estado, Ciudad, 
 Telefono, CorreoElectronico, Contraseña)VALUES('$name', '$street', '$house', '$postal', '$country', 
 '$state', '$city', '$phone', '$email', 
 /$password/)";
 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$re);
 if($resultado){
 printf("Si");
 }else{
 printf("No");
 }
 $conexion->close();
?>
```

insertamos los datos:

[image: inserto estos datos:]
y esta es la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no logro hacer que inserte los datos :( me manda a la siguiente pagina e imprime que No ¿Qué podría ser lo que este fallando?

Comment: @BetaM listo me salio este error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�a) VALUES('pablo', '1910', '215', '47800', 'Mexico', 'Jalisco', 'Ocotlan',' at line 1

Comment: @BetaM Si, ya los quite pero sale que el error esta en el telefono, en la base de datos le puse que es un int 10 unsigned

Comment: @BetaM me da el mismo error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�a) VALUES('pablo', '1910', '215', '47800', 'Mexico', 'Jalisco', 'Ocotlan',' at line 1